# How to install stomp on php 7.3 + ubuntu?

Tags: stomp

I am using ubuntu 14.4 and PHP 7.3, I want to know that how to install PHP stomp.
I have tried with this command: "sudo pecl7.X-sp install stomp" and I am getting this response: "sudo: pecl7.X-sp: command not found".

Comment: do you use composer?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: First download compatible package from https://pecl.php.net/package/stomp
- Step 2: Open the terminal and  go to your stomp tgz packages path and run below command
- Step 3: pecl install -f  stomp-2.0.2.tgz (your package file name)
- Step 4: You should add "extension=stomp.so" to php.ini
- Please check on the link [cleck here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-Stomp-on-PHP-7-3-Ubuntu)